# Making boxes in css and html and placing them in a grid

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a start page of sorts, and I want it to look somewhat like this: https://imgur.com/zjzKyRD (poorly made, but the program I used was really bad(I miss mspaint))

I originally used buttons, which made it really easy to link and customise, but I had some issues with size, so I tried with a div, but I can't seem to make the whole div box a clickable link. If I am able to figure that out, I still need to place the boxes in specific places and I have no idea how.

The question: How can I make these boxes, place them in a grid like formation and have them link to different sites? Would it also be possible to make a function where I can hover over one of the "sites" and it would show me some information about it? (manually entered)

Please keep in mind I'm really new to this, so an explanation would be nice :P Thanks.

Edit: Didn't include any code, here it is:

CSS ("borrowed" from w3)

```
.button {
margin-left: 150px;
margin-top: 50px;
background-color: #4CAF50;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 16px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
cursor: pointer;}

.button1 {
background-color: #ffbf80;
color: black;
border: 2px solid #ffbf80;
min-width: 350px;
width: 350px;}

.button1:hover {
background-color: white;
color: #ffbf80;}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank" class="button button1">Google</a>
```

Thats just one of the buttons, but the others are basically the same, but with different links, margins and colours(colors?). 
When using multiple boxes they appear below each other, not besides each other. I have messed around with a bunch of different margin settings, a few things I found online when browsing around but nothing seems to align them properly.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Alright, sorry. Ill include some code, but I didn't really see the point as it doesn't work :P Ill edit the q now, thanks for letting me know in a pleasant way ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd suggest that you use some grid framework, such as Bootstrap or Foundation. Nobody writes websites in plain HTML anymore.

Secondly, I think you can use the a-tag and change the css so that it's an inline-box. Especially if you're only going to use them as links and not do anything fancy (such as some dynamic animations). You should probably have a container class around those to represent a row. As follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="linkbox" href="link1"> Link 1 </a>
    <a class="linkbox" href="link2"> Link 2 </a>
    <a class="linkbox" href="link3"> Link 3 </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a class="linkbox" href="link4"> Link 4 </a>
    <a class="linkbox" href="link5"> Link 5 </a>
    <a class="linkbox" href="link6"> Link 6 </a>
</div>
```

Check out this fiddle with accompanied css https://jsfiddle.net/wwk4tyzw/2/

Comment: Not allowed to comment on the question yet so I'll put it here. I tried your code on jsfiddle @Kossi, and the boxes seemed to stack besides each others. What browser do you use? https://jsfiddle.net/p61cmf9k/

Comment: Im using safari at the moment :( But I have tested ShamPooSham's code, and edited it a little and it seems to work fine :) Now the issue is that its not centered. Ive tried adding <center> but it doesn't seem to properly centre it when I don't have it in fullscreen. Also, how can I reduce the size of open space between them? When I resize the window, the boxes go under each other way before they get close to each other. Here is the "updated" fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kossi/bzw64ug9/

Comment: Okay, could you give me some other alternatives to centre the boxes?

Comment: The center tag is deprecated, don't use it. You should change the css. With all your requirements, I'd really suggest using a grid framework as I suggested before. It helps a lot. I made an update which centers the container, but I didn't resolve your other problems, I can't do everything for you ;) https://jsfiddle.net/f7mm0k4a/

Comment: The code you sent just made it worse.. xD https://imgur.com/a/17XHO Thanks for all the help though, I really do appreciate it :* EDIT: Just kidding, it worked :P

Comment: lol okay. Please mark my answer as resolving your issue if you feel like it did.

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's probably going to be more relevant in the future i want to throw this in here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/